# Hessian Matrix for VBA coding

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

Does Anyone have the VBA code written for the Hessian matrix to plug two functions? I have it for the jacboan matrix. I have it written using x and y slopes.

```
`Private Sub Hessian_Click()

Dim x, y, Step, z0, z1, xSlope, ySlope, yxSlope, xySlope

x = Val(InputBox("Input value of x to evaluate derivative at"))
y = Val(InputBox("Input value of y to evaluate derivative at"))
Step = 0.00001
'Step = Val(InputBox("Input step size"))

'Calculate Parital Central derivative of x in first function

z0 = f1xy(x - Step - Step, y)
z1 = f1xy(x + Step + Step, y)

xSlope = (z1 - z0) / (2 * Step)

'Calculate Parital Central derivative of y in first function

z0 = f1xy(x, y - Step - Step)
z1 = f1xy(x, y + Step + Step)

ySlope = (z1 - z0) / (2 * Step)

'Values for first row in Hessian Matrix

Cells(20, 1) = xSlope
Cells(20, 2) = ySlope

'Calculate Parital Central derivative of x in second function

z0 = f2xy(x - Step - Step, y)
z1 = f2xy(x + Step + Step, y)

xSlope = (z1 - z0) / (2 * Step)

'Calculate Parital Central derivative of y in second function
z0 = f2xy(x, y - Step - Step + Step)
z1 = f2xy(x, y + Step + Step - Step)

ySlope = (z1 - z0) / (2 * Step)

yxSlope = (ySlope - xSlope) / (2 * Step)

xySlope = (yxSlope - ySlope - xSlope) / (2 * Step)
'Values for second row in Hessian Matrix
Cells(21, 1) = xSlope
Cells(21, 2) = ySlope



End Sub''
```

Comment: you could edit your post and use {} icon on top of your edit section to add your code. It's recommended to add the related tags as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting